# Count the number of elements in a list field in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm still learning to use DSL queries in ElasticSearch. I have documents where one field is a list. I need to count the number of documents that have one element in this field, two elements in this field, etc. For example, here is a document structure:

Document1:

```
"Volume": [
{
"partition": "s1",
"fieldtype": ["A","B"]
}
]
```

Document 2:

```
"Volume": [
{
"partition": "s1",
"fieldtype": ["A"]
}
]
```

Document 3:

```
"Volume": [
{
"partition": "s1",
"fieldtype": ["B"]
}
]
```

I need a way to calculate that there is one document with 2 elements in fieldtype field and 2 documents with one element in fieldtype.
If I try to aggregate them like this:

```
"size":0,
"aggs": {
"name": {
"terms": {
"field": "fieldtype.keyword"
}
}
}
```

I get counts of elements (number of As and Bs). Without using keyword, I get an error.

Comment: Do you want the documents and size array or qts of elements?

Comment: I would like to get the number of documents that have a certain array length. Like this: ten documents with array length 1, five documents with array length 2, and two document with array length 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rabbitbr provided a good answer, but I could not understand why we tried to use a nested field. And, I think we need to use terms aggregation instead of sum here. Anyhow, here is a solution without nested :

```
PUT idx_test

POST idx_test/_bulk
{"index":{ "_id": 1}}
{"Volume":[{"partition": "s1","fieldtype": ["A","B"]}]}
{"index":{ "_id": 2}}
{"Volume":[{"partition": "s1","fieldtype": ["A"]}]}
{"index":{ "_id": 3}}
{"Volume":[{"partition": "s1","fieldtype": ["B"]}]}

GET idx_test/_mapping

GET idx_test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "size": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['Volume.fieldtype.keyword'].size()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Without using keyword, I get an error.

This is normal because without `keyword` you are trying to build an aggregation on a field whose type is `text`.

Here the response for the query above which is pretty basic query :

```
{
  ....
  "aggregations": {
    "size": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "2",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, we have 2 documents with 1 sized array and we have 1 document with 2 sized array.

Answer (score 1):

I imagined that you work with nested type. Below is my solution:

```
PUT idx_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Volume": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST idx_test/_bulk
{"index":{ "_id": 1}}
{"Volume":[{"partition": "s1","fieldtype": ["A","B"]}]}
{"index":{ "_id": 2}}
{"Volume":[{"partition": "s1","fieldtype": ["A"]}]}
{"index":{ "_id": 3}}
{"Volume":[{"partition": "s1","fieldtype": ["B"]}]}

GET idx_test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "doc_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "volumes": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Volume"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "size": {
              "sum": {
                "script": {
                  "lang": "painless",
                  "source": "doc['Volume.fieldtype.keyword'].size()"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Respons:

```
 "aggregations" : {
    "doc_id" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "volumes" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "size" : {
              "value" : 2.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "2",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "volumes" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "size" : {
              "value" : 1.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "3",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "volumes" : {
            "doc_count" : 1,
            "size" : {
              "value" : 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your solution. I actually do not have nested fields in this case. Also, I'm not putting this data to ElasticSearch, I only have an access to it, so I only know the fields within "Volume".

Comment: You have access a kibana devtools and can run get idx_name and show us the type Volume field?

Comment: You must replace idx_name to real index name.

Comment: Execute get _cat/indices

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Here is the structure: {“dbname”: {
 “aliases”: {},
 “mappings”: {
  “properties”: {
  “ProviderFieldType”: {
  “properties”: {
   “Types”: { 
    “type”: “text”,
    “fields”: {
     “keyword”: {
     “type”: “keyword”: ,
     “ignore_above”: 256
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: so far, I used ProviderFieldType.Types.keyword to address the Types subfield

Comment: i dont see this fields? "Volume": [
{
"partition": "s1",
"fieldtype": ["A","B"]
}
] .
Where is field "Volume"?

Comment: provide the first document with de array after this command: GET dbname/_search

Comment: well, I myself added Volume in order to define different documents. As I mentioned, I'm really just started to learn ElasticSearch. "fieldtype" in my question actually corresponds to ProviderFieldType.Types. I changed it to simplify my question.